# Pester PowerShell testing for a sample script is not working as expected

Tags: powershell, pester

Hi all I have a written a sample script to find whether the given string is Palindrome or not as follows

```
function Palindrome1([string] $param)
{
  [string] $ReversString
  $StringLength = @()

  $StringLength = $param.Length

  while ( $StringLength -ge 0 )
 {
    $ReversString = $ReversString + $param[$StringLength]
    $StringLength--
 }    

 if($ReversString -eq $param)
 {
    return $true
 }
else
{
    return $false
}
}
```

And this is my `.tests.ps1`

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -replace '\.Tests\.', '.'
. "$here\$sut"

Describe "Palindrome1" {
    It "does something useful" {
        Palindrome1 "radar" | Should Be $true
    }
}
```

Below is Invoke script

```
$modulePath = "D:\Pester-master\Pester.psm1"
$SourceDir = "E:\Pester"
Import-Module $modulePath -ErrorAction Inquire
$outputFile = Join-Path $SourceDir "TEST-pester.xml"

$result = Invoke-Pester -Path $SourceDir -CodeCoverage "$SourceDir\*.ps1" -PassThru -OutputFile $outputFile

$result
```

I am not getting the expected result can some one tell me where I am doing wrong

Comment: What result do you see?

Comment: in my xml I am getting as follows `<message>Expected: {true}
But was:  {}</message>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
[string] $ReversString
```

is a value expression resulting in an empty string. That empty string is output by the `Palindrome1` function every time your run it. Change it to:

```
[string] $ReversString = ''
```

Comment: Hi one more help when I make the input parameter as Mandatory it is asking me multiple time to enter the string `function Palindrome1
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
 param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $param 
    )`

Comment: Not able to reproduce, it only prompts once if argument is not present. Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you need help with parameters

Comment: find here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955495/pester-powershell-testing-prompting-to-enter-the-input-multiple-times