# Pester PowerShell testing prompting to enter the input multiple times

Tags: powershell, pester

```
function Palindrome1
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $param
    )

    [string] $ReversString
    $StringLength = @()

    $StringLength = $param.Length

    while ($StringLength -ge 0)
    {
        $ReversString = $ReversString + $param[$StringLength]
        $StringLength--
    }

    if ($ReversString -eq $param)
    {
        return $true
    }
    else
    {
        return $false
    }
}
```

My `.tests.ps1`

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
. "$here\Palindrome1.ps1"

Describe -Tags "Example" "Palindrome1" {
    It "does something useful" {
        Palindrome1 | Should Be $true
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you mark a parameter `Mandatory`, you MUST supply an input value to it - otherwise it will prompt you for one.

From [`Get-Help about_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847824.aspx):

```
 PARAMETER ATTRIBUTE TABLE
 [...] 
   Parameter Required?
     This setting indicates whether the parameter is mandatory, that
     is, whether all commands that use this cmdlet must include this
     parameter. When the value is "True" and the parameter is missing
     from the command, Windows PowerShell prompts you for a value for
     the parameter.
```

Change your test to:

```
Describe -Tags "Example" "Palindrome1" {
    It "does something useful" {
        Palindrome1 -param "value goes here" | Should Be $true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Mathias

Comment: Hi but the test case is failing when I am passing radar as input any idea

Comment: @Dotnet Still has the same flaw as in the other question you posted (`[string] $ReversString` still results in an empty string)

Comment: I made it to empty but I couldn't see the expected result

Comment: @Dotnet If I take your function as it is in your question, change `$ReversString` as suggested in the other answer and then run your tests with "radar" as the input parameter, it works (+ test succeeds)

Comment: You mean to say like this `Palindrome1 -param "radar" | Should Be $true`

Comment: But instead if I would like to read it from command is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120966/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-dotnet).

Answer (score 1):

If you update your param block like this

```
param (
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string] $param = $(throw "a parameter is required")
)
```

Your test will fail as expected without prompting for input.